# CometD over AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, cometd

I want to integrate cometD as push technology in my application and I have problems to find any information both in cometD and AWS groups about their compatibility.

I've tried to integrate webSockets with STOMP over Sock.js but I couldn't make it work because of AWS ELB round robin nature. It sends connect request to one instance and next request to another which doesn't have a clue about any connection. So, I had to drop the implementation.

So I have two instances behind ELB with https protocol. I can't switch to TLS because of couple infrastructure reasons. I can't use sticky session as well.
Please, note that I don't want to use webSockets. I want to implement pub-sub notification system over technologies like poling/streaming etc.

My question is how well cometD works with AWS ELB? Is there any problems with ELB round robin nature. Can CometD work using one tunnel request?

**Update.**
I can not use webSocket because some clients can have proxies which doesn't support upgraded http protocol.
As @sbordet mentioned in comments cometD won't work without sticky load balancer which I can not support. That is why my updated question would be:
Is there any comet like technology/library/framework which can work with AWS ELB without stickiness on multiple instances? Maybe something that will open one connection and handle all data transfer within that connection?

Comment: You say you cannot use sticky session (but don't explain why), but actually AWS ELB [allows stickyness](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html). For CometD to work with HTTP, it needs a sticky load balancer, based either on a cookie or on client address. For CometD to work with WebSocket, it needs a sticky load balancer based on client address.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use TCP listeners, rather than HTTP listeners, in your AWS ELB for your long-lived WebSockets (and/or cometD) sessions.

Comment: @sborden, I can not use sticky session because I have web farm which scales by load balancer. If I add stickiness it won't work as required.

Comment: @Castaglia, I can not use TCP listeners because I don't want to manage ssl certificates on instances. Also as I mentioned I don't want to use webSockets because some of the clients can have proxies which doesn't support upgraded http protocols.

Comment: How about using an SSL listener, then?  The ELB manages the SSL session, but you still get the long-lived TCP connections (not request based) balanced among your backends?

Comment: @Castaglia, what about client's proxies which doesn't support TCP? I can not rely on WebSocket. I need some alternative way.